# What happens when two creatures are giving lifelink to my spells?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play [Firesong and Sunspeaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Firesong%20and%20Sunspeaker)

> Red instant and sorcery spells you control have lifelink.

and use [Helm of the Host](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20the%20Host) to make a copy of it. If I then use a spell like [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt), will that trigger two separate instances of lifegain, meaning I gain 6 life rather than 3?

Comment: It may be worth noting for future readers that the life gained from lifelink does not _trigger_ - that is, it's not a triggered ability which goes on the stack and can be responded to. If you want to edit, perhaps using a different word like "cause" instead of "trigger" would remove that potential confusion.

Comment: @DavidZ "It may be worth noting for future readers that the life gained from lifelink does not trigger" Some of the older cards with the ability explicitly written out rather than keyworded do, however.

Comment: @nick012000 That's not lifelink

Answer (score 9):

The [Comprehensive rules](https://media.wizards.com/2023/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020230414.txt) state that

> 702.15f Multiple instances of lifelink on the same object are redundant.

so, no: you'll gain only three life.